# Adding to "unknown values"

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add 90 to a random number and keep adding 90 to the new values that are made. I've been looking for a long time but couldn't find it, is there an easy way to do this;

Have a value: `let value = 0`
-- Add 90 to that value: `let newValue = value + 90` -- not only once but forever. Keep adding 90 to the new values of the let without knowing what they will be?

Comment: This seems so trivial that I must not be properly understanding your question...

Comment: 'forever' ? and do what with this infinite number of values exactly?

Comment: Can you provide more context? This is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a generator?

```
class Plus90 {
  func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Int> {
    var current = 0
    return anyGenerator {
      let oldValue = current
      current += 90
      return oldValue
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
let p90 = Plus90().generate()

for _ in 1...5 {
  print(p90.next()!)
}
```

This will print 0, 90, 180, 270, 360 etc.

And if you don't always want to start from 0, change the method like this:

```
class Plus90 {
  func generate(x: Int) -> AnyGenerator<Int> {
    var current = x
    ...
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
let p90 = Plus90().generate(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you do:

```
var value = 0
```

or

```
var value = <your random value>
```

And then:

```
value += 90
```

And this last line anytime you want to add `90` to `value`...